# aframe - ar.js don´t show model gltf in mobile android

Tags: android, mobile, aframe, gltf, ar.js

(sorry for my inglish) 
In the web shows correctly, but in mobile Android not. The mobile have a 5.1.1 Android version and show correctly 3d objets like CUBES, but not a GLTF model.

I couldn't try it in a newer Android version, maybe that's it?

````
<html>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

    <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <a-scene embedded arjs>

        <a-marker type='pattern' url='pattern-2.patt' registerevents>

            <a-box  shader= flat position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 1;' scale="0.5 0.5 0.5">
                <a-animation attribute="rotation"
                    dur="3000"
                    to="0 -360 0"
                    repeat="indefinite"
                    easing= "linear">
                </a-animation>
            </a-box>

            <a-entity
                position="0 1 0"
                scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"
                gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf"
            ></a-entity>
        </a-marker>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: i think u might have a similar problem to what i have : https://stackoverflow.com/q/62033734/2496170 ... ?

Comment: I'm going to try some of that and see what happens. Thank you!